# R Finding elements matching with each other within a vector

Tags: r, pattern-matching, stringdist, agrep

I have a list of addresses.  These addresses were input by various users and hence there are lot of differences in the way a same address is written.  For example,

```
"andheri at weh pump house", "andheri pump house","andheri pump house(mt)","weh andheri pump house","weh andheri pump house et","weh, nr. pump house"
```

The above vector has 6 addresses.  And almost all of them are the same.  I am trying to find the matches between these address, so that I can club them together and recode them.

I have tried using `agrep` and stringdist package.  With agrep I am not sure if I should each address as a pattern and match it against the rest.  And from the stringdist package I did the following:

```
library(stringdist)
nsrpatt <- df$Address
x <- scan(what=character(), text = nsrpatt, sep=",")
x <- x[trimws(x)!= ""]
y <- ave(x, phonetic(x), FUN = function(.x) .x[1])
```

The above gives me the error:

```
In phonetic(x) : soundex encountered 111 non-printable ASCII or non-ASCII
  characters.
```

Not sure if I should remove those elements from the character vector or convert them to some other format.

With agrep I tried:

```
for (i in 1:length(nsrpattn)) {
  npat <- agrep(nsrpattn[i], df$address, max=1, v=T)
}
```

The length of the character vector is around 25000 and this keeps running and stalls the machine.

How do I effectively find the closest match for each one of the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run a small cluster analysis on your data.

```
x <- c("wall street", "Wall-street", "Wall ST", "andheri pump house", 
       "weh, nr. pump house", "Wallstreet", "weh andheri pump house", 
       "Wall Street", "weh andheri pump house et", "andheri at weh pump house", 
       "andheri pump house(mt)")
```

First, you need a distance matrix.

```
# Levenstein Distance
e  <- adist(na.omit(tolower(x)))
rownames(e) <- na.omit(x)
```

Then, a cluster analysis can be run.

```
hc <- hclust(as.dist(e))  # find distance clusters
```

Derive the best cutpoint, e.g. graphically, and "cut the tree".

```
plot(hc)
```

[image]

```
# cut tree at specific cluster size, i.e. getting codes of similar objects
smly <- cutree(hc, h=16)
```

Then you can build a key data frame, which which you can check if the matches are right.

```
key <- data.frame(x=na.omit(x), 
                  smly=factor(smly, labels=c("Wall Street", "Andheri Pump House")),
                  row.names=NULL)  # key data frame
key
#                            x               smly
# 1                wall street        Wall Street
# 2                Wall-street        Wall Street
# 3                    Wall ST        Wall Street
# 4         andheri pump house Andheri Pump House
# 5        weh, nr. pump house Andheri Pump House
# 6                 Wallstreet        Wall Street
# 7     weh andheri pump house Andheri Pump House
# 8                Wall Street        Wall Street
# 9  weh andheri pump house et Andheri Pump House
# 10 andheri at weh pump house Andheri Pump House
# 11    andheri pump house(mt) Andheri Pump House
```

Finally replace your vector like so:

```
x <- key$smly
```

Comment: thank you...sounds like a good idea....I will try and come back.

Comment: Very pretty method. The only problem is that adist(x) is O(n^2), so for 25,000 strings with an average string length of 30 characters this would take over 2 hours, at least on my machine. It's not obvious that it's possible to do better than O(n^2) though.

Comment: I found another option with agrep here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825215/group-together-levels-with-similar-names-r`.  Unlisting the groups with list number as classification variable, attaching it back to the data frame through a match helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: @jay.sf I will accept this answer and it help me to think beyond agrep's and amatch's.