# Find similar names in a vector in R

Tags: r

The data is as follows:

```
abc <- c('New York','New Yorkk','Paris','Pari',"Dublin")
```

I want to find similar names in this vector and make a resulting data frame that has the count of similar names and non-similar names.

The output should be like the result generated by the following data frame:

```
results <- data.frame(Length = length(abc),
                      Similar_names = 2,
                      Not_Similar_Names=1)
```

Comment: Define similarity.

Comment: How exactly do you define similar? Is this specifically for city names? I'm sure there are a lot of valid city names that are different by one letter.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541292/r-finding-elements-matching-with-each-other-within-a-vector

Comment: Well, the actual data doesn't have exact city names. I need to use cosine similarity or fuzzy logic to get the result

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/05/how-to-apply-text-distances-and-fuzzy-joins/